# Jump to string an website without an anchor

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

Is it possible, probably using javascript, to jump to a particular sentence (string) via a link on a website?

Like an anchor, only without the anchor in HTML.

This is an example from the search results, searchstring was "content directory":

```
Result: <a href="https://aaa.de/sss/planets/">planets/</a> on line 20: <br>
If you create a folder within the content directory (e.g. <code class="hljs lua">content/<span class="hljs-built_in">sub</span></code>) and...
```

After the link has been opened, the browser should jump to this line (The line number is of course only the one from the searched text file.) and like to color the search string.

Comment: Not downvoting, but why would you not want to use an anchor? Is there a specific use-case?

Comment: Justified question, the string is the line in which the search string is located. That is independent of the HTML tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some usefull script: http://www.seabreezecomputers.com/tips/find6.htm
It offers a On-Side-Search-Button